# Conditional model rules in Yii

Tags: php, validation, yii, frameworks, yii-components

I'd like to add some extra validation to a Yii model.

I know it is simple enough to add in some logic to say a form field must be an exact length of 6 characters, however is it possible to set the rule to say the following:

```
if ($_POST['code'] == '')
    then no validation needed
else
    code string must be exactly 6 characters in length
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your model  add this rule , if `code` is an attribute

```
public function rules()
{
    return array(
       array('code', 'length', 'is'=>6, 'allowEmpty'=>true),          
    );
}
```

for more Info , [Yii length validator](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/56/#hh15)

Answer (score 0):

Go through this, you will get your answer,
[Yii validator](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/56/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
 public function rules() {
        return array(
            array('code', 'length', 'is' => 6, 'allowEmpty' => true)
        );
    }
```